# how to display only aggregate or flagged results in a Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query that gets break time exceptions.  I use Case statements to flag the records.  The problem is, I only want to list those that are flagged or have a "1" in the Skipped break, or "ShortBreak" column?

```
SELECT        lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, SUM(TotalHours) AS TotalHours, DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(dtTimeOut), MAX(dtTimeIn)) AS BreakTime, 
                         CASE WHEN SUM(ftc.TotalHours) > 6 AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SkippedBreak, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, 
                         MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 30 AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ShortBreak
FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc
WHERE        (DID IS NOT NULL) OR
                         (DID IS NOT NULL) AND (dtTimeOut IS NULL)
GROUP BY lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, TotalHours
```

Comment: How is what you want different from what you currently have?

Comment: right now it lists all entries.  I really only want employees that have worked over 6 hours, and have either taken a break less than 30 minutes, or did not take a break at all...

Comment: This will list all employee entries even those with breaks 30 minutes or over.  Which I do not care about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot filter in the `WHERE` part of the query you've got, because the grouping is not yet performed at that point. You can use a `HAVING` clause to do additional filtering after grouping:

```
SELECT        lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, SUM(TotalHours) AS TotalHours, DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(dtTimeOut), MAX(dtTimeIn)) AS BreakTime, 
                     CASE WHEN SUM(ftc.TotalHours) > 6 AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SkippedBreak, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, 
                     MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 30 AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ShortBreak
FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc
WHERE        (DID IS NOT NULL) OR
                     (DID IS NOT NULL) AND (dtTimeOut IS NULL)
GROUP BY lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, TotalHours
HAVING SUM(ftc.TotalHours) > 6 AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 0
OR DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 30 AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) > 0
```

Or you can use a subquery, and filter the results of the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT        lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, SUM(TotalHours) AS TotalHours, DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(dtTimeOut), MAX(dtTimeIn)) AS BreakTime, 
                     CASE WHEN SUM(ftc.TotalHours) > 6 AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SkippedBreak, CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, 
                     MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 30 AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ShortBreak
FROM            dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc
WHERE        (DID IS NOT NULL) OR
                     (DID IS NOT NULL) AND (dtTimeOut IS NULL)
GROUP BY lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, TotalHours
) AS sub
WHERE sub.SkippedBreak = 1 OR sub.ShortBreak = 1
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful.  I liked the way you suggested a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `HAVING`

```
...
HAVING ((
    SUM(ftc.TotalHours) > 6
    AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 0
) OR (
    DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 30
    AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) > 0
))
```

Comment: That won't work. You cannot use aggregate functions in the `WHERE` part, because it's evaluated before the `GROUP BY` part.

Comment: Error: An aggregate may not appear in the Where Clause unless its in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference