# How to add a Case Statement for an aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query that gets time clock and break time exceptions.  If someone doesn't take a break, the break time is a negative number.  I need to report the "BreakTime", however I need to change negative break minutes to '0' otherwise report the break minutes.

My query is:

```
SELECT lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, 
       TotalHours, BreakTime, SkippedBreak, ShortBreak
FROM (
    SELECT lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, 
        SUM(TotalHours) AS TotalHours, 
        DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(dtTimeOut), MAX(dtTimeIn)) AS BreakTime, 
        CASE WHEN SUM(ftc.TotalHours) > 6 
              AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 0 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
        END AS SkippedBreak, 
        CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) < 30 
              AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(ftc.dtTimeOut), MAX(ftc.dtTimeIn)) > 0 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
        END AS ShortBreak
    FROM dbo.fTimeCard(@StartDate, @EndDate, @DeptList, 
                       @iActive, @EmployeeList) AS ftc
    WHERE (DID IS NOT NULL) 
       OR (DID IS NOT NULL) 
      AND (dtTimeOut IS NULL)
    GROUP BY lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName
) AS sub
WHERE (SkippedBreak = 1) 
   OR (ShortBreak = 1)
```

Right now my output looks like this:

```
Bob Bibby   6.03    -362
Rob thomas  10.53   -632
Bret smith  7.6 17
Ron blah    8.1 25
```

I need the negative breaktime minutes to be "0"

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display only aggregate or flagged results in a Case statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721824/how-to-display-only-aggregate-or-flagged-results-in-a-case-statement)

Comment: It's a question derived from my findings of the last question.  It a different question.  I'm now trying to change the result of "Breaktime" if it's less than 0

Comment: It will be much easier if you provided a simple `input` data and corresponding `output` data (result) for the query you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your query in an outer query that uses a `CASE` to handle the negative aggregated values:

```
SELECT
    lEmployeeID, sFirstName, sLastName, TotalHours, 
    CASE WHEN BreakTime < 0 THEN 0 ELSE BreakTime END AS BreakTime,
    SkippedBreak, ShortBreak
FROM (
    <your current query>
) t
```